# What kind of roof flashing is this and is it up to code?

Tags: code-compliance, roofing, flashing

This is in NJ. Roof was recently done and I've never seen this anywhere else. Looks like aluminum screwed in on both sides and the front. It's a very steep pitch. Either 10/12 or 12/12.

Any idea what this is? Is this some sort of hack/short cut? What can you tell me about this if anything?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you it is inappropriate and must have been installed by someone that doesn’t understand flashing and counter flashing principles.

The Code is clear, “The exterior walls shall provide a weather resistant wall envelope, ...including flashing.” (See ICC R703.1)

The flashing should have been “step flashing”, as specified by the Code: “Approved corrosion resistant flashing shall be installed SHINGLE FASHION in a manner to prevent entry of water...” (ICC R703.4) That is a continuous flashing not step flashing in a shingle fashion. If they don’t understand how it’s done, they can see an illustration at Figure R703.4.1.

In addition, the step flashing should have a “kickout” as shown in Figure R703.4.1

That flashing creates a  space for water to get trapped and could backup into the wall/roof. It needs to be removed and replaced with step flashing.

Comment: How could it have passed inspection like that?

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY I doubt if they saw it. Inspections are just a “general review process”. Did they get a Building Permit? It’s not always required. I’d call the local Building Permit Office and give them your address.

Comment: There was a permit. There's no drip edge either. I'm pretty sure that's also not up to code. Any chance you can look up the code for me please?

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY Code says “drip edges are required at eaves and rakes of composition shingle roofs.” (See ICC R905.2.8.5)

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY Nailing is usually wrong too.  Are those GAF Timberline, if so, the manufacturer requires the nails to be between 5 3/4” and 6 1/4” from bottom edge of shingle and 6 nails are required due to pitch of roof. I’m sure the underlayment was not installed correctly. If anything is wrong you’ll loose your guarantee and the manufacturer will not be able to help you. Look at installation instructions https://www.gaf.com/en-us/document-library/documents/residentialroofing/shingles/timberlineamericanharvest/timberline_series_application_instructions_english_spanish_french.pdf